# Are many two column indexes a bad smell?

Tags: index-tuning, h2

I have table that contains failures. (15000 rows + on a abstract embedded system)

A failure has the following fields:

- id *PK BIGINT*
- errorNumber *INT*
- source *VARCHAR*
- raisedAt *BIGINT*
- clearedAt *BIGINT*
- cleared (computed column for sorting purposes = clearedat>0) *BOOL*

My first use case Is that I want to display all failures, the uncleared ones first.

`Select * from FAILURES ORDER BY CLEARED asc, raisedAt desc;`

Second use case is by a synchronization job. I want to delete all synchronized and **cleared** failures, there for all failures with an id smaller X and cleared

`DELETE FROM FAILURES WHERE ID <? AND CLEARED;`

Third use case is that I want to pick a specific uncleared failure.

`SELECT * FROM FAILURES WHERE SOURCE=? AND ERRORNUMBER=? AND NOT CLEARED;`

This would lead me to the following indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX CLEARED_RAISEDAT_SORTED_FAILURES ON FAILURE_MANAGER.FAILURES (cleared asc,raisedat desc);
CREATE INDEX CLEARED_ID_FAILURES ON FAILURE_MANAGER.FAILURES (cleared asc,id desc);
CREATE INDEX CLEARED_SOURCE_SORTED_FAILURES ON FAILURE_MANAGER.FAILURES (cleared asc,SOURCE desc,ERRORNUMBER desc);
```

I sometimes still struggle with index definition. It seems odd to me that I have 3 different indexes, which all only differ in the second column. Relative to my described uses cases, are these indexes feasible or does this create unnecessary overhead? Are there any check up questions that I can ask my self to figure if this might be the correct setting?

Comment: What is your database?

Comment: I use h2 1.4.196

Comment: You are using a Java database on an embedded system?  Or were you already using Java for your application too?

Comment: In technical terms it's actually not embedded. We have a onboard processor with memory, that can run linux system on which we run our java application. We only feel the hardware performance limitation.

Comment: Why is `ERRORNUMBER` not part of `CLEARED_SOURCE_SORTED_FAILURES`?

Comment: @Lennart Oh that's definitely a miss. Missing this one would prevent the index to be used. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I hope for you that most failures are cleared.  In that case, when you query for cleared failures, the index will hurt performance.  If you'd put that column in the second place, on the other hand, it might be benificial.  When you're looking for not cleared - if those are rare - the index will help.

Comment: Most failures will be cleared indeed. I probably will have up to 20 open failures at once. This is coincidence though. Lets assume it would be the opposite. Why would it hurt? I thought that it simply wouldn't bring any benefit.

Comment: Using an index while it would be better to do a full table scan, can bring performance to its knees.  But for now, keep in mind that 15.000 records is nothing.

Comment: I always thought that in worst case a bad index is as performant as a full table scan. Looks like this is a may be a misunderstanding with impact. Why is a full index scan worse that a full table scan?

Comment: We work on a embedded system, therefore we don't have the usual server performance :) We already feel bad indexs with 15000 rows, that's why I currently try to optimize it.

Comment: The index may not contain all data you need - I see you selecting "*"  (don't!).  In that case, the database has to skip from index to table continuously.  I assure you, it is a magnitude slower.

Comment: I feel your pain ;-)   It won't cost you much to try, will it?  Inverse the index columns for the searches on "cleared".   BTW, that column shouldn't exist, you should query "where clearedAt is (not) null".

Comment: I inserted the `cleared` column for sorting purposes. If it would not exists, I would need to `ORDER BY CASE WHEN  clearedAt=null` THEN 1 ELSE 0 asc, raisedat desc` which is much more expensive as I understand. I'm surprised about the `*` fact. I always thought that db uses the index to find the right row and then executes the query on the referenced row in the main table. Thanks a lot. I'll see what I can improve with this additional information. "Much to learn I still have"

Comment: That would be "order by clearedAt nulls last, raisedat desc".

Comment: I mixed up a little detail. It's `0` not null. Legacy code...

Comment: "order by -clearedAt, raisedat desc", would give you the most recently cleared first, those not cleared last.  At the end of that list, those not cleared ordered by raisedat descending.  I must say the use of such order escapes me.